# One month old Macbook Air does not power on

Tags: mac, macos

I have an almost new Macbook Air. I started to use Time Machine for the first time with a brand new "My Passport" hard drive. I had to unplug it during the process and it was left unplugged for quite some time. Then it went to sleep probably or maybe not, but I plugged it. Then unplugged again (one charger was shared between two Macs).

Cannot turn it on now! The light on the plug cord is green as it is fully charged.
I changed the socket just in case. I tried with USB My Passport drive plugged in and not. Nothing happens.

Comment: Take it to the shop. It is still covered by the warranty unless you did something silly to void it.

Answer (score 4):

Keep pressing your power on button for 5 seconds.
The press it again for normal power-up.

You could also try this: [Apple Support Page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964)

Comment: Thanks, worked. Though, I tried that before, just did not press and hold long enough. So, first Time Machine backup should go without interruption. I had an option checked when backup gets interrupted on power supply disconnected.
Corrupted backup recovery is a [long process](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88677/how-to-prevent-sleep-while-a-time-machine-backup-is-in-progress).

Answer (score -3):

Try this article very clearly Explain might help someone with mac issues

http://itrepairguide.com/apple-macbook-pro-not-power-on-no-sign-of-life/